# Node fibers/future callbacks with more than one argument

Tags: javascript, node.js, future, node-fibers

How does futures handle a callback that has more than one argument? This is critical to just about every use I could have for futures. The github example shows it only handleing one argument.

The example from the [Github Readme](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers) is

```
var fileNames = readdir('.').wait();
```

But what about something a mysql call like

```
client.query("select * from employees", function(err, results, fields) {
    // callback function returns employees array
    callback(results);
});
```

How would I get those three (`err`, `results`, and `fields`) using the futures `wait()` method?

**Edit**

Experimentation has taught me that the first argument of the callback, in this case `err`, is always treated as an error and is thrown if the value is truthy. The second argument is assigned. Any further arguments are ignored as best as I can tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a wrapper for client.query, returning one *data* parameter with both results.

```
 client.prototype.query2 = function ( sql, callback ) {
      this.query(sql,
              function(err, results, fields) {
                  var data={result:result, fields:fields};
                  callback(err,data);
              }
 };
```

I've recently created simpler abstraction than 'futures', also based on Fibers. 
I haven't tested my code with a real world DB example yet. Please try it and help me test it if you can: https://github.com/luciotato/waitfor

Comment: Very clever. I won't have time to get into this code for a while, but this looks the part. Thanks!